# for loop and if statement in python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am confused by the below codes. They look similar but work differently.

I can understand why the **first** one works. Could somebody kindly explain why the others work or not work? thanks a lot.

```
print([x for x in range(1, 11) if x % 2 == 0]) # This works

print([x if x % 2 == 0 else 0 for x in range(1, 11)]) # This works

print([x for x in range(1, 11) if x % 2 == 0 else 0]) # Not work

print([x if x % 2 == 0 for x in range(1, 11)]) # Not work

print([x if x % 2 == 0 else -x for x in range(1, 11)]) # This works
```

Comment: Why do you say the last one doesn't work?

Comment: @Samwise The first one is the reference.  The last one does not produce the same result.  So it doesn't "work".  Although the second-to-last one doesn't work either, even though it claims to.

Comment: The second to last one produces a different result, though, and it says `This works`.

Comment: It's called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in the documentation. The `if` at the end is called an "`if` clause".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easiest to understand if you build the expression piece by piece.

```
>>> [
    x 
    for x in range(1, 11)
]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

This is the simplest form.  We're taking every `x` in `range(1, 11)`.  The thing that goes into the list is `x` itself.

```
>>> [
    x if x % 2 == 0 else 0 
    for x in range(1, 11)
]
[0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10]
```

Now we're iterating over the exact same values of `x`, but we're not simply putting `x` into the comprehension.  Instead the thing that goes into the list is `x if x % 2 == 0 else 0`.  We still have the same number of values, as in the previous example, but now all the odds values have been transformed into 0.

```
>>> [
    x
    for x in range(1, 11)
    if x % 2 == 0
]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Now we're back to just putting `x` in the comprehension result, but we've eliminated every other `x` from the iteration.  Note that the `if` goes at the end of the expression (after the `for...in` part), and its only function is to filter which values `x` receives at the start of the expression (it can't replace them with something else, only include or exclude them).  That's why we now have half as many values.

We can't add an `else` to the filter expression at the end because what the condition does is already defined; there is no block of code to execute and no `else` to do as an alternative.  The `if` is "include this value" and the `else` is "don't include this value".

Similarly, if we use an `if` in the expression at the beginning we **must** include an `else` to specify what the value turns into if the condition is not true.

Answer (score 1):

An `if` clause at the end of a list comprehension is part of the [comprehension syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), used to filter the elements. It does not make sense for it to have an `else` because it is really only a predicate to specify whether the element is included or not.

An `if` in the first part of a list comprehension is part of a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions). It must have an `else` to be syntactically valid, but it is not a filter: it is not used to exclude elements from the comprehension, but to specify different values based on a condition.